# Code works correct in Thonny but not in terminal. RPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, terminal, multiprocessing

I'm new to Python and tried to make a little script at my RPI with Raspberry.
My problem is that the code works great in Thonny, but when I load it in LXTerminal, some functions don't works right.

When i do my calculation in Thonny and i press button21 for 30 seconds the effectively (round((effectivelytime / refresh)*100)) value will be 50% but when i do the same in terminal effectively will be 0, but if i don't press button21 at all the effectively will be 100.

It's like the effectivelytimer just sending "full value" or nothing.

Does anyone have an idea?

```
!/usr/bin/env python

import pyodbc
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
from gpiozero import Button
from threading import Thread

button21 = Button(21)
button20 = Button(20)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=****;PORT=1433;DATABASE=****;UID=****;PWD=****;TDS_Version=8.7;')
counter=Value('h', 0)
x=Value('h', 0)
refresh = 10
elapsed_stoptime = 0
effectivelytime = 1
effectively = 0
precounter = 0

def function1():
    while True:
        global effectivelytime
        global effectively
        global precounter
        effectivelytime = x.value
        effectively = round((effectivelytime / refresh)*100)
        if counter.value == precounter:
            effectively = 0            
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ****.dbo.****(counter, effectively) VALUES ({},{})'.format (counter.value, effectively,))
        cnxn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        print("Printed To DB - Counter = ", counter.value, ", Effectively = ", effectively,)   
        x.value = 0
        precounter = counter.value
        time.sleep(refresh)

def function2():
    button21.wait_for_release()
    counter.value = counter.value + 1
    print (counter.value, "Cykel")

def effectivelytimer():
    while True:
        if button20.is_pressed:
            x.value = x.value + 1
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)


def trigcounter():
    t2 = Thread(group=None,target=function2)
    t2.start()

button21.when_pressed = trigcounter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(group=None,target=function1)
    t3 = Thread(group=None,target=effectivelytimer)
    t1.start()
    t3.start()
```

I don't receive any error messages at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thonny uses Python 3. The shebang line of your script (`!/usr/bin/env python`) refers to Python 2. Try changing `!/usr/bin/env python` to `!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: Thank you so much!
That was a easy problem which drove me crazy!